# Proving a basis spans $R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Doing some reviewing and I'm not 100% sure if my thought-process is correct.

I have the following two vectors and need to prove they're a basis for $R^3$:

$$B=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\
        0 \\
        -1 \\
        \end{bmatrix},
  \begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        1 \\
        -1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Now these two vectors are linearly independent, and now I have to prove they span $\Re^3$.

So I have two arbitrary scalars: $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that belong to R:

$$\alpha
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\
        0 \\
        -1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}+\beta
  \begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        1 \\
        -1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}=
 \begin{bmatrix}
        x \\
        y \\
        z \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Not much solving to do here

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & x \\
        0 & 1 & y \\
        -1 & -1 & z \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

I am left with:

$\alpha = x$, $\beta=y$ and $-\alpha - \beta=z$

Now what I'm having difficulties understanding is how this basis can span all of $R^3$ with z being: $-\alpha - \beta=z$

Comment: its not a basis. Basis of $R^3$ have 3 elements

Answer (score 1):

Its linearly independent but does not span whole $R^3$. For example $(1,0,0)$ does not belong to span of those two vectors.